# Linker error while linking Mono to C++ project on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, mono

I'm working on linking Mono into my Mac C++ project using CMake and I've gotten most of the way there. Here is my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.3)

project(IgnisEngine VERSION 0.1
                    DESCRIPTION "Game engine"
                    LANGUAGES C)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/monoTest.c)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/MacOS/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/pkgconfig")
pkg_check_modules(MONO REQUIRED mono-2)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${MONO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${MONO_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${MONO_LIBRARIES})

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${MONO_CFLAGS}) # This and following line shouldn't be necessary
target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${MONO_STATIC_LDFLAGS})

include(CMakePrintHelpers)
cmake_print_variables(MONO_INCLUDE_DIRS MONO_LIBRARY_DIRS MONO_LIBRARIES MONO_CFLAGS MONO_STATIC_LDFLAGS)
```

I set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to the directory in the Mono framework that has mono-2.pc.
I haven't used PkgConfig with CMake before but this seems to be working fine, as here are the variables it defined from this in the output console:

```
MONO_INCLUDE_DIRS="/Users/mickey/Documents/GitHub/IgnisEngine/libraries/MacOS/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/mono-2.0" ; 
MONO_LIBRARY_DIRS="/Users/mickey/Documents/GitHub/IgnisEngine/libraries/MacOS/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib" ; 
MONO_LIBRARIES="mono-2.0;iconv;pthread" ;
```

The compiler and linker flags look quite good too (though again I don't have much experience with this):

```
MONO_CFLAGS="-D_THREAD_SAFE;-I/Users/mickey/Documents/GitHub/IgnisEngine/libraries/MacOS/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/mono-2.0" ; 
MONO_STATIC_LDFLAGS="-L/Users/mickey/Documents/GitHub/IgnisEngine/libraries/MacOS/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib;-lmono-2.0;-liconv;-lpthread"
```

This is monoTest.c:

```
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {
    MonoDomain *domain;

    domain = mono_jit_init ("test.cs");
}
```

The full path to jit.h is:

`/Users/mickey/Documents/GitHub/IgnisEngine/libraries/MacOS/Mono.framework/Headers/mono-2.0/mono/jit/jit.h`

This seems to be consistent with MONO_INCLUDE_DIRS above.

Currently this all compiles and makes just fine, so on the compiler side we're good. The problem now is on the linker side, since when I run I get the following error:

```
[build] ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/mickey/Documents/GitHub/IgnisEngine/libraries/MacOS/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/libmono-2.0.dylib, file is universal (i386,x86_64) but does not contain the arm64 architecture: /Users/mickey/Documents/GitHub/IgnisEngine/libraries/MacOS/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/libmono-2.0.dylib
[build] Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
[build]   "_mono_jit_init", referenced from:
[build]       _main in monoTest.c.o
[build] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

This is the error I'd like to resolve. I have a few questions here:

1. How does CMake know whether to link dynamically or statically? I would like CMake to link statically to /Users/mickey/Documents/GitHub/IgnisEngine/libraries/MacOS/Mono.framework/Libraries/libmono-2.0.a , though I'm not sure how to specify this.
2. Is the warning above about ignoring libmono-2.0.dylib the reason this isn't working? If the linker is looking there for the function definitions, then that would explain the error, though I'm not sure why it's happening in the first place.

I have verified through `nm libmono-2.0.dylib | grep mono_jit_init` that both libmono-2.0.a and libmono-2.0.dylib do contain defined symbols for _mono_jit_init. I would appreciate any help with this, thank you.

Edit: Some extra info: monoTest.c was originally monoTest.cpp, but I switched to C because I thought the linker problem could be due to name mangling. That didn't seem to resolve the issue though.

Comment: Another part of the error message you seem not to have focused on in your questions, but probably should: "_libmono-2.0.dylib, file is universal (i386,x86_64) but does not contain the arm64 architecture_"

Comment: Yes that's what I was referring to in my question 2. I haven't been able to figure out why I'd be getting that warning, but I'd appreciate any info on that too. Mono appears to be supported on my OS (MacOS Ventura), and there doesn't seem to be much info online about this error. The error option could be I downloaded the wrong library, but this is what was installed from the Mac installer on the Mono website, and i just copied the entire library into my project repo which I don't see why that would cause a problem.

Comment: I also don't fully understand the meaning of the error. "File is universal"? And why would it not contain the arm64 architecture? Any info on that would be appreciated too

Comment: see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary. As for "_And why would it not contain the arm64 architecture?_", ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯